# IntelliJ doesn't Understand java libraries on Java9-ea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am using **jdk9-ea 149** and created a sample **javafx application**

IntelliJ doesn't understand the java libraries, It's shows all the import statement in **red color** and they are all **grayed out**.even for **java.util.List, java.util.ArrayList** it has the same issue.

I am able to compile form outside but i am not able to compile the code from **IntelliJ 2016.3.2 Ultimate Edition**.

It looks like we need to add some libraries to IntelliJ project but with **java9 build 149**  jigsaw i don't know how to do that.

[image: Sample JavaFx Code On Intellij using jdk9-ea]

**I am using Experimental features still it doesn't understand the import statements - see intellij setting below**

IntelliJ Version : **IntelliJ 2016.3.2 Ultimate Edition**
Java Version: java 9-ea build: 149
[image]

Comment: Re-opened, hope you get a correct answer soon! But as said before: then you should add which version of IntelliJ you are using.

Comment: And mention the exact Java 9 version you are using.

Comment: @jindal_manish I *know* that this is tagged IntelliJ, but if you are like me and what to learn jdk-9 features with the latest build 149, you *can* use eclipse, until IntelliJ fixes it's builds. Here is the relevant bug that I've opened and they fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509354

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.1 is Out](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/12/intellij-idea-2016-3-1-is-out/):

> Speaking of JDK 9, IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 won’t support builds 148 and up because they contain code that breaks things. Of course, we’re working to resolve this, and will support the latest JDK 9 builds in 2017.1 (its EAP may well start within the next few weeks).

In [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1: Java 9, Kotlin 1.1, Spring, Gradle, JavaScript, Go and more](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/intellij-idea-2017-1-java-9-kotlin-1-1-spring-gradle-javascript-go-and-more/) it says:

> The latest builds of JDK 9 are fully supported, with assisted project import and coding assistance for editing module declarations.

So if you are using Java 9 build 148 or higher, you need to use version 2017.1 or higher.

Alternatively, if you need to use an older version of IntelliJ, downgrade to Java 9 build 147 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of IntelliJ IDEA, 2017.1, does support [jdk 9](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/intellij-idea-2017-1-java-9-kotlin-1-1-spring-gradle-javascript-go-and-more/).